# Convert first day of month to Last day of month in Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, momentjs

I am very new to angular JS but since morning struggling with this.

I have a datepicker with "MM/yyyy" format, the date value returned here is first day of month.
i.e. February 1, 2017 but i want the date as February 28, 2017 i.e last day of month.

Just to update i am using moment function.

Please suggest some work around for the same!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I infer from your question that you are using `momentjs`.

This lib provides you with a built in function `endof`

```
const date = new Date(2017, 1) // 1st Feb    
moment(date).endOf('month');
```

This should handle most cases directly including `leap years`

Answer (score 2):

If you have a JavaScript [`Date`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) instance `d`, you can simply use

```js
const d = new Date(2017, 1) // 1st Feb
d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1)
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)

console.info(d.toLocaleString())
```

Now `d` will be the last day of the month.

---

Note: this easily handles year boundaries without any extra code. For example

```js
const d = new Date(2017, 11) // 1st Dec
console.info('Before', d.toLocaleString())

d.setMonth(d.getMonth() + 1)
d.setDate(d.getDate() - 1)

console.info('After', d.toLocaleString())
```

Comment: This is a good shorthand way to do it, but remember that by doing this you're depending on the Javascript engine (which varies among versions, browsers, and platforms) to do the conversion for you as you expect it to do, so this will be prone to bugs. It's always better to only depend on your code to do the proper conversions by itself, rather than blindly relying on something else outside it, like the JS engine implementation.

Comment: @ablopez what *"conversions"* are you talking about? If you're referring to the year boundary issue (ie, setting the month to `12`), you'll need to show me an example of it not working. I don't believe the behaviour here varies at all between JS engines. See https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate#Description

Comment: I never said it wouldn't work. What I'm saying is that relying on implementation specifics to fix a logic flaw in your own code is bad practice my friend. If you do this in other code you write (unrelated to this) you're just following a lazy pattern of programming, and will increase the probability of bugs in your code overall.

Comment: @ablopez I have no idea what you're talking about. It literally says it will behave this way in the specification. I don't see any logic flaw at all

Comment: Just because it says so in a specification doesn't mean it will *always* behave that way, specially when it comes to HTML, CSS and Javascript, in which each browser along the years has sometimes had its own way of implementing minute details of the specifications in their own way. Just thinking of IE or Safari when saying this. Finally, you're referencing the Mozilla specification, which other browsers may not necessarily adhere to. But again, I'm talking here about a general programming principle, not specifically about this SO question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You just need add 1 month to the date, and then substract 1 day. Here's an example:

```
// Let's suppose the date selected from the picker was February 1st, 2017
// Remember months in JS are zero-index based, so 0=Jan, 1=Feb, etc.
var selectedDate = new Date(2017, 1, 1);

var month = selectedDate.getMonth();
var year = selectedDate.getFullYear();

month ++;

if(month > 11){ // Last month number is 11 (December)
  month = 0; // January
  year ++;
}

var oneMonthAheadDate = new Date(year, month, 1);
var lastDayOfSelectedMonthDate = new Date(oneMonthAheadDate.getTime() - (1000 * 3600 * 24)); // We substract 1 day (1000 ms x 3600 secs in an hour x 24 hours in a day)
```

Your needed date will be in `lastDayOfSelectedMonthDate`